# Sorting ranking by trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, ranking, leaderboard

I create a game in which players will gain levels. The basic information is in the table "**char**" (nickname, lvl, exp, money ...).

I want to make a ranking that will be updated on a regular basis and works in real time. I think it makes no sense to perform the "ORDER BY lvl" operation on the "char" table every time someone enters the "Ranking" tab on the site.

**My plan is this:**

1) Make an additional table: "**ranking**" in which the data will be physically sorted.

2) Create a **trigger** that will update the ranking every time someone reaches a new level or someone creates a new character. Does it make sense and is more efficient?

If so, how can I do it? If not, how else to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you want to do the 'ORDER BY char.lvl' every time someone visits the "Ranking" page? This is normally how such operations are performed in a relational database.

De-normalizing (the act of duplicating data/indexes for performance reasons) is really what you are suggesting. Duplicating the relevant data in your 'ranking' table would work, but consumer more space.

Now, there's nothing inherently wrong with de-normalizing or using triggers, but I don't see a real reason to add this complexity (but you'd know better - did you try this and the performance was below expectations?).

You could create an index on the lvl column, which will make queries much faster for sorting. (See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html for more information on indexes). It would be quicker to update a secondary index like this, and less memory/processor intensive than re-building the 'ranking' table.

If the additional index proved to be insufficient, then the trigger + additional table may workout well...

By "physically sorted", I presume you mean having a primary key (versus a secondary index). But what would this key include? Perhaps lvl + nickname? I'd still lean towards an index on lvl+nickname if that were the case.

And, this begs some additional questions... Can users change their nickname? Would a new level also increase their experience?